# Hide 'add to cart' button ONLY on woocommerce shop/category pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to hide the button on my shop pages, but I would like to show it on other posts and pages.

I've found this code to hide the add to cart button on my whole website:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );

function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
}
```

How can I tweak it, so it only removes the button on woocommerce shop and catagory pages?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the Woocommerce conditional tags to check:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/

```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );

    function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
      if( is_product_category() || is_shop()) { 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please can you tell me which file I need to add this too? I've tried loads with no joy... Thanks

Comment: @Lyall or others, this can be added to functions.php in your WordPress theme.

Comment: Note that if you make this change in the original functions.php, it will be overwritten by WordPress updates.  To keep your changes permanently, make sure you either create a child theme to override the default function in your WordPress theme or place this piece of code in code snippets. 
https://www.dreamhost.com/wordpress/create-woocommerce-child-theme/
https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-code-in-wordpress-without-breaking-your-site/

Answer (score 1):

This could also be done with CSS by targeting the relevant classes:

```
.cart{display:none;}

.avia_cart_buttons{display:none;}
```

In my case there is that avia because i use Enfold Theme. With inspect element find out your class where the buton is located. and declare it invisible.

Another example is:

```
.woocommerce .products .shop-column.product-hover-style-2 .product-content 
.product-add-to-cart-btn{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: CSS could actually help. In my case `a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart{display:none;}` did the trick. Simple advice for answers on Stackoverflow, do not blame on the other answers. Just replace _Why are you hacking at functions when there is an easy method here you go_ with _Custom CSS could do what you require_.

Answer (score 1):

```
    add_action('wp','only_add_bierkoerier_in_cart', 'woocommerce_before_cart');  

    function only_add_bierkoerier_in_cart() {

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {


    $bierkoerier_in_cart = false;
    $categories = get_categories();

    if ( has_term( 'bierkoerier', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $bierkoerier_in_cart = true;
        break;
    } 
    }

    if($bierkoerier_in_cart) {  
        wc_print_notice( 'omdat u bierkoerier producten in uw winkelwagen heeft 
    kunt u geen winkelitems toevoegen', 'notice' );
       if(is_shop() || is_product() || is_product_category()) {
         remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
         remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the **"Add to cart"** button 
You need to use hook which not affect other code-

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_loop_button', 1 );
function remove_loop_button()
{
if( is_product_category() || is_shop()) { 
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
}
}
```

this will remove add to cart button from shop/category pages .

> Here you can get WooCommerce Action and Filter Hook
>   -https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin you can use to remove hide disable add to cart button https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-options/

Answer (score 0):

That's quite simple as i have gone through several tutorials when i was trying to fix it . You have to just put this code in woocommerce.php to hide add to cart button for shop page.

```
function WpBlog() {
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
  return WooCommerce::instance();
}
```

Hope that would work for you, if not let me know i will guide you

Answer (score 0):

To remove add to cart buttons from shop, product category, and single product pages, use below steps:

1. Locate the functions.php in child theme.  Child theme prevents changes been overwritten by WP updates. 
   https://www.dreamhost.com/wordpress/create-woocommerce-child-theme/
2. Put below code in functions.php:

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );
function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
      if( is_product_category() || is_shop()) { 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
      }
    }

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_before_cart' );
function woocommerce_before_cart() {
      if( is_product()) { 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',30);
      }
    }