# Remove "add to cart button" from loop (Wordpress Theme: Avada)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I want to remove the "add to cart button" everywhere except on the single-post.

I have tried this solution:

[Hide 'add to cart' button ONLY on woocommerce shop/category pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976296/hide-add-to-cart-button-only-on-woocommerce-shop-category-pages)

It has not worked for me though. I am guessing it is because of the template I am using: Avada. It looks like the template is using different hooks than the normal woocommerce hooks. With the hook-names that I found in the files, I've tried this:

> ```
> add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );
>
>  function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
>      remove_action( 'avada_woocommerce_buttons_on_rollover', 'avada_woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart',10 );
>  }
> ```

It doesn't do anything. Does anybody have an idea what I need to do?

Edit:
There is a file class-avada-woocommerce.php with those lines

```
add_action( 'avada_woocommerce_buttons_on_rollover', array( $this, 'template_loop_add_to_cart' ), 10 );
...
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

If I remove the first line of those two in the parent theme files the add-to-cart-button disappears. So I know that this is the hooked action I need to remove but I just can't manage to remove it.

Therefore I have also tried each of those lines:

```
remove_action( 'avada_woocommerce_buttons_on_rollover', 'avada_woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart',10 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');

remove_action( 'avada_woocommerce_buttons_on_rollover', array( $this, 'template_loop_add_to_cart' ), 10 );

remove_action( 'avada_woocommerce_buttons_on_rollover', 'template_loop_add_to_cart' , 10 );
```

Answer (score 3):

I also stuck with this issue, because `remove_action` didn't work for me. And only by browsing a woocommerce template's code I figured out that they use filters for calling this button. So try this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'hide_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function hide_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        $html = '';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Modify it for your needs. I also use Avada and it works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Need to override Avada Woocommerce hooks. Add this code to functions.php

```
function remove_woo_commerce_hooks() {
    global $avada_woocommerce;
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', array( $avada_woocommerce, 'template_loop_add_to_cart' ), 10 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_woo_commerce_hooks' );
```

Comment: not the first answer, but only complete and correct, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this bellow code into functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
```

Then let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it, but it doesn't change anything. The reason probably is that there exists a file called class-avada-woocommerce.php with the following lines:
`add_action( 'avada_woocommerce_buttons_on_rollover', array( $this, 'template_loop_add_to_cart' ), 10 );
...
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
`

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to remove `add to cart` button from shop page as you are missing `$avada_woocommerce` which is variable used for avada woocommerce.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', array( $avada_woocommerce, 'show_details_button' ), 15 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It didn't work for me though. I've also adapted the line to this `remove_action( 'avada_woocommerce_buttons_on_rollover', array( $avada_woocommerce, 'template_loop_add_to_cart' ), 10 );` but still no luck.