# How to hide 'Add to Cart' button with PHP only in a specific page ID?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on E-commerce project and I'm want to hide the add to cart button from a specific page (i.e ID 231). I know how to do that with `CSS` but I want to do it in `PHP`.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: take help of this post:- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161711/how-to-get-current-page-id-outside-the-loop

Comment: Can you be more specific about in exactly which page you want to hide add to cart button?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'woocommerce_cloudways_purchasable');
function woocommerce_cloudways_purchasable($cloudways_purchasable, $product) {
return ($product->id == your_specific_product_id (like 22) ? false : 
$cloudways_purchasable);
}
```

I hope its work for you

Comment: I think this filter is for disable add to cart button for specific product id.. op is asking for hiding cart button in specific page id.. Will it work with page id too?

Comment: Thy this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976296/hide-add-to-cart-button-only-on-woocommerce-shop-category-pages

Comment: It is for the shop and category page only op has not defined in which page he want to remove the button.

Comment: Add to cart button comes only a few woo commerce pages can you tell which page you want to remove

Comment: I haven't ask the question buddy. i asked you because i am not sure that this hook works for page id or not.

Answer (score 0):

Another Option can overwrite the single-product page of Woocommerce.

add_filter( 'template_include','locate_template',30 );

public function locate_template( $template ) {

```
        $pre_template = $template;
         if ( is_single() && 'product' == get_post_type() )
        {   

            $template = locate_template( array( 'woocommerce/single-product.php' ) );

            if ( ! $template ) {
                global $post;
                $product_id = $post->ID;

                if( isset( $product_id ) && !empty( $product_id ) && $product_id == 231 ) {

                    $template = YOUR_DIR_PATH.'woocommerce/customized_temp.php';
                }
                else{
                    return $pre_template;
                }
            }
        }
        return $template;
    }
```

After this, you can create the customized_temp.php and then simply overwrite the single_product.php file (and can easily remove the add_to_cart button)

With the help of the above code, you can easily override any template
In your case:

Please visit below path: Woocommerce > templates > single-product > add-to-cart > simple.php